# VBA Function returning #VALUE! when trying to refer to Optional Parameter

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to calculate a NPV of several cashflows with continuous compounding. However when trying to refer to the optional parameter (which signals that the NPV will be continuous compounding), i get #VALUE! instead of a valid NPV

My VBA code is as follows:

```
Function myNPV(r As Double, CF As Range, Optional rate_type = 0)

Sum = 0
t = 0
For Each Cell In CF
    Sum = Sum + Cell.Value / (1 + r) ^ t
    t = t + 1
Next Cell

If rate_type = 1 Then
    Sum = Sum + Cell.Value / ((Exp(1)) ^ (r * t))
    t = t + 1
End If

myNPV = Sum

End Function
```

The first of the formulas calculates a non-continuous-compounded NPV, which is why I've introduced the optional parameter to choose between the two parameters.

When testing out my formula as follows: `"=mynpv(C10, C3:C8, 1)" (C10 = discount rate, C3-C8 = Cash flows and 1 refering to the rate type)`, I simply get #Value!

Comment: You're referring to `cell` after the `for each cell` loop has ended.

Comment: Please put 'Option explicit' as the first line in each of your module/class/forms.  Make sure you do 'Debug.Compile Project' before trying to run your code.  You may also benefit from installing the free and fantastic Rubberduck addin for VBA and checking the code inspections.  You code is replete with bad practises.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you want to include both inside the loop and then use an IF to decide which to do:

```
Function myNPV(r As Double, CF As Range, Optional rate_type = 0)

Sum = 0
t = 0
For Each Cell In CF
    If rate_type = 0 Then
        Sum = Sum + Cell.Value / (1 + r) ^ t
    Else
        Sum = Sum + Cell.Value / ((Exp(1)) ^ (r * t))
    End If
    t = t + 1
Next Cell

myNPV = Sum

End Function
```